# How to resolve PHP Laravel Sql Insert error?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

When I press the buy button I get this error

QueryException in Connection.php line 729:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'qty' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `orders` (`user_id`, `product_id`, `qty`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (3, 1,    , 2018-10-06 20:44:27, 2018-10-06 20:44:27))

first of all, I'm a beginner so I'm still learning and I do not know if some of this is correct, all I want is when I press the buy button it will display the form and I will type the quantity then submit and my quantity will increase and the products inventory will decrease and if I deleted my order, The products will increase again (I did this and I think it will work) and the user can update his quantity and if someone ordered something the seller cannot delete it, only update his inventory as same as the buy button way and  the form, and if the users ordered all products it will display (out of stock) with a dead link button, I am training, It is not homework and I do not know how to write all functions..

this is the Buy button

```
<li><span><a href="/add_order/{{ $product['id'] }}">Buy</a></span></li>
```

which should pop up the next form when I press it,

this is my form code for the buy button

```
<form method="POST" action="/add_order/{{ $product['id'] }}" class="klaviyo_subscription_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <input type="hidden" name="g" value="LIST_ID">

    <div class="klaviyo_fieldset">
        <p class="klaviyo_header">Please define quantity you need, then order it.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="klaviyo_fieldset">
        <div class="klaviyo_field_group{{ $errors->has('qty') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <label for="k_id_modal_$email" style="display: block; text-align:center">Quantity</label>               
            <input type="number" id="k_id_modal_$email" name="qty" style="display: block; margin:auto">

            @if ($errors->has('qty'))
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('qty') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="klaviyo_fine_print"></div>

    <div class="klaviyo_form_actions">
        <button type="submit" class="klaviyo_submit_button">
            <span>Order Now</span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="klaviyo_below_submit" ></div>
</form>
```

**OrderController**

```
public function store(Request $request, $id)
{
    $product = Product::find($id);
    $order = new Order();
    $order->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $order->product_id = $id;
    $order->qty = $request->get('qty');
    $product->inv = $product->inv - $order->qty;
    $order->save();
    $product->save();

    return redirect('/');
}
```

thanks for reading :D

Comment: @Juan It's not solution of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Request is object and not array!** You need to use method to get request value. Check updated code

```
  public function store(Request $request, $id)
  {
    $product = Product::find($id);
    $order = new Order();
    $order->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $order->product_id = $id;
    $order->qty = $request->get('qty');
    $product->inv = $product->inv - $order->qty;
    $order->save();
    $product->save();
    return redirect('/');
  }
```

This will work if logic for passing "qty" to request is correct. You can do dump of request and die inside store function, to make sure about this fact.

Comment: @Nader Then you have another problem. Most probably there -->

value="{{ $order['qty'] }}

Where $order is defined? If it's not something like "hidden" input why you need this?

Comment: ok, I removed it. I did not notice it because I copied the code from another page, but the same error

Comment: @Andre Did you enter the number for input with name "qty" ??? If you want it to be nullable, then allow it for the entity field...

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand you well, but I noticed now when I make that column null in the database, everything will work fine but the products will stay as it is and the orders will stay null there is no quantity, but if you deleted your order.. the product will get increased more than the original inventory

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is you sending the data with the `POST` method.

But you access the data from the `GET` method.

**OrderController**

```
$order->qty = $request->get('qty');   // this is where you are wrong.
```

Change this either,

```
$order->qty = $request->post('qty');
```

or,

```
$order->qty = $request->qty // this is the preferred approach.
```

Comment: first one displayed this

BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74:
Method post does not exist.

and the second one syntax error, unexpected '$order' (T_VARIABLE)

Answer (score 0):

In your database table filed "qty" set default value null or as default 0.
and write

```
$order->qty = $request->qty;
```

it will work fine